# How to set default product thumbnail image on WooCommerce even if there is an existing product image?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I set a default product thumbnail on WooCommerce even if there is an existing product image on a product, but will not replace or change the existing one on the database? Hope someone can help, thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to replace all product images with any thumbnail without replacing existing product image?

Comment: Yes, I want to set a default product image thumbnail to all the products without replacing existing product image.

Comment: Let me know it my solution helped you. If yes please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
function alterImageSRC($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon) {
        
    $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage.jpg';

    return $image;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

All right so let me explain the solution for you. You have to remove product loop original image thumbnail with the remove action. Then you have to insert new action which is calling the custom thumbnail. Don't forget to replace `URL OF YOUR IMAGE HERE` with your image URL. For a single  product you have to do the same. This code goes into functions.php file of your theme. Tested and works.

```
//Product loop

function custom_image_woo() {
    // Remove original product image from product loop
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_image_woo', 10 );
    // Your custom image thumbnail function
    function here_is_the_magic() {
        echo '<img src="URL OF YOUR IMAGE HERE">';
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'here_is_the_magic', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'custom_image_woo');

// Single product page

//this removes product featured image

add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'main_image_away', 10, 2);
function main_image_away($html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;
    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image )
        $html = '';
    return $html;
}

//this will add your image before gallery

function gallery(){
    echo '<img src="URL OF YOUR IMAGE HERE">';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'gallery', 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you bro, It worked with the thumbnails in the gallery but not in the product post itself. I want also to appear in the product post to make it the main product image.

Comment: My mistake for the wrong term I used, it should be the product image of the product posts. I tried to create another question but it prompted me "You can only post once every 90 minutes."

Comment: @BlogMarkz No problem. I have updated my answer try it now. I will appreciated a upvote and mark my solution as the right one :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort bro, but it didn't worked for me. I posted an answer below that worked. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: @BlogMarkz all right but that I have tested my code on my local woocommerce website and it worked perfectly. Maybe you have some builder or something which is not compatible. Otherwise you are welcome.